# How to create a Regex expression that accepts an Empty String/ null values?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write up a regular expression that accepts **numbers**, **decimals** as well as an **empty string / null value**.

My current expression accepts decimal values that are dot separated. The numbers can start with either a - (minus) or + (plus). Additionally, the value can start with a decimal point - for instance: .56

Here is the expression:

`/^([-+]?(\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d*))?$/`

How can I refactor it to accept an **empty string**/ null value?

Answer (score -1):

You can write something like this :

/^(?:[-+]?(\d+|.\d+|\d+.\d*))?$/

or maybe just append null using pipe:

/^(?:[-+]?(\d+|.\d+|\d+.\d*))?$/|null